# CSS selection by class given in a top div (Bootstrap 4 navbar)

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am using a bootstrap navbar and want to style the li elements in normal an collapsed mode but i dont figure out the right way ... all my tries end with style both the same or nothing :-(

This is the html output in normal:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md" role="navigation">

<div class="container">


<button class="navbar-toggler collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#womo-navbar" aria-controls="womo-navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
<span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>

<div id="womo-navbar" class="navbar-collapse justify-content-md-center collapse" style="">

<ul id="menu-menu-1" class="nav navbar-nav">

<li itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-26" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home active menu-item-26 nav-item"><a title="Startseite" href="http://localhost/" class="nav-link" aria-current="page">Startseite</a></li>

<li itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-27" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children dropdown menu-item-27 nav-item"><a title="Activity" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle nav-link" id="menu-item-dropdown-27">Activity</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="menu-item-dropdown-27" role="menu">
<li itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-44" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-44 nav-item"><a title="adadasdad" href="http://localhost/?page_id=42" class="dropdown-item">adadasdad</a></li>
</ul>
</li>

<li itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-28" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-28 nav-item"><a title="Beispiel-Seite" href="http://localhost/?page_id=2" class="nav-link">Beispiel-Seite</a></li>

<li itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-29" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-29 nav-item"><a title="Members" href="http://localhost/?page_id=6" class="nav-link">Members</a></li>
</ul>
</div>    
</div>
</nav>
```

This is the html collapsed:

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md" role="navigation">

<div class="container">


<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#womo-navbar" aria-controls="womo-navbar" aria-expanded="true" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
<span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
<div id="womo-navbar" class="navbar-collapse justify-content-md-center collapse show" style="">

<ul id="menu-menu-1" class="nav navbar-nav">
<li itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-26" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home active menu-item-26 nav-item"><a title="Startseite" href="http://localhost/" class="nav-link" aria-current="page">Startseite</a></li>

<li itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-27" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children dropdown menu-item-27 nav-item"><a title="Activity" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle nav-link" id="menu-item-dropdown-27">Activity</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="menu-item-dropdown-27" role="menu">
    <li itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-44" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-44 nav-item"><a title="adadasdad" href="http://localhost/?page_id=42" class="dropdown-item">adadasdad</a></li>
</ul>
</li>

<li itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-28" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-28 nav-item"><a title="Beispiel-Seite" href="http://localhost/?page_id=2" class="nav-link">Beispiel-Seite</a></li>

<li itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-29" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-29 nav-item"><a title="Members" href="http://localhost/?page_id=6" class="nav-link">Members</a></li>    
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</nav>
```

The only difference ist the show class in the womo-navbar div:

normal:

```
<div id="womo-navbar" class="navbar-collapse justify-content-md-center collapse" style="">
```

collapsed:

```
<div id="womo-navbar" class="navbar-collapse justify-content-md-center collapse show" style="">
```

So i wnat to style the li in two differnt ways depending if the show class in womo-navbar is present or not.

Sorry for my bad english

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
#womo-navbar.show ul>li.nav-item{
  //your style
}
```

This will only affect the `li` that are inside the navbar that have the show class.

Comment: Thank you for the very quick reply !
But im soory that i have to say it dont work in this case :-(

At the moment i use li.nav-item {} but with it i syle both ...
Thank you

Comment: Oh you should have mentioned that. The reason why it is not working is that the `li.nav-item` has more precedence. In that case let me update the answer and let me know if it works.

Comment: Sorry but no ... i dont find the right selector for this ..
I also deleted the style for li.nav-item {} completly and 
tried out both versions ...
When i style  li.nav-item {} alone it work but for both normal and collapsed.
Thank You !

Comment: oh sorry. My bad, I just noticed that is should be an id not class. I will update the answer again. Sorry about that.

Comment: Works perfectly THANK YOU !

I should figure out more about how to get to the right selectors !
Thanks

Comment: No problem :)) I am glad to help you.